# Defining variables in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to define some variables based on the code below.
I'm trying to achieve following

1. I want to read file path from a cell in a sheet . Also in the code I want the name of active xlsm file to be flexible . The name of the current file is "Summary overview to customer.xlsm", I want to use ThisWorkbook or something instead to make it flexible.
2. Also I want the name of the other file "protreat report".xlsx" to be variable as the current code will not work if the file name is changed.
   Hopefully someone can assist me or direct me to right path. I do not want to use hard coded path and file name.

```
Sub OpenAndClosWorkbook()
'Open a workbook
'Clear sheets
    Dim sheetOne As String, sheetTwo As String, sheetThree As String, Path
    sheetOne = "Compressor blocks"
    sheetTwo = "Expander blocks"
    sheetThree = "Pump blocks"
    
    'Clear data and formatting in sheets one and two
    Sheets(sheetOne).Select
    Cells.Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Selection.ClearFormats
    
    Sheets(sheetTwo).Select
    Cells.Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Selection.ClearFormats
    
    Sheets(sheetThree).Select
    Cells.Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Selection.ClearFormats

'Open method requires full file path to be referenced.
  Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\test\protreat report.xlsx"
  
'Copy compressor block and paste in summary sheet.
    Workbooks("protreat report.xlsx").Worksheets("Compressor Blocks").Range("A1:BY1000").Copy _
    Workbooks("Summary overview to customer.xlsm").Worksheets("Compressor Blocks").Range("A1")
    
'Copy Pump block and paste in summary sheet.
    Workbooks("protreat report.xlsx").Worksheets("Expander blocks").Range("A1:BY1000").Copy _
    Workbooks("Summary overview to customer.xlsm").Worksheets("Expander blocks").Range("A1")
    
'Copy Pump block and paste in summary sheet.
    Workbooks("protreat report.xlsx").Worksheets("Pump blocks").Range("A1:BY1000").Copy _
    Workbooks("Summary overview to customer.xlsm").Worksheets("Pump blocks").Range("A1")

 Workbooks("protreat report.xlsx").Close
End Sub
```

Comment: If "Summary overview to customer.xlsm" is the workbook containing this code, then change all instances of `Workbooks("Summary overview to customer.xlsm")` to `ThisWorkbook`. I suspect this is not actually the case tho.

Comment: Use a workbook variable: `Dim wb As Workbook`, `Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\test\protreat report.xlsx")`, then replace all instances of `Workbooks("protreat report.xlsx")` with `wb`.